# Angular: how to run a function only when data is retrieved asynchronously?

Tags: angularjs

I have two files:

**index.html:** which I want to use a *custom directive* in:

```
<body>   
    <div ng-controller="friendsController">
        <random-friend friends="friends" title="'Random Friend'"></random-friend>
    </div>
</body>
```

**app.js:** which contains:

- **controller:** has `$scope.friends` which assigned its value *asynchronously*, and will be used in the custom directive.
- **custom directive** that outputs a random friend (element) each time the page loads.

Code:

```
// Module
const myApp = angular.module('myApp', []); 

// Custom Directive
myApp.directive('randomFriend', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            friends: '=',
            title: '='
        }, 
        template: `<h4>{{friends[randomIndex]}}</h4>`,
        controller: function generateRandomNumber($scope) {
            $scope.randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.friends.length); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        }
    };
}]);

// Controller 
myApp.controller('friendsController', ['$scope', $scope => {
    $http.get('data/friends.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.friends = response.data;
    });
}]);
```

The problem is that when the code gets to `$scope.friends.length`, the console returns an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" because the request data isn't retrieved yet.
So, how to run the function `generateRandomNumber()` only when the friends array is retrieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this using ng-if

```
 <div ng-controller="friendsController">
  <div ng-if="friends.length > 0">
        <random-friend friends="friends" title="'Random Friend'"></random-friend>
  </div>
 </div>
```